# How can I load a SQLITE database from a buffer with the C API?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, stream, buffer

I am trying to load a database from the memory instead of opening a .sqlite file. I have read the C/C++ API reference but I can not find the proper method.

The buffer I am trying to load is simply an sqlite file loaded in memory. I just want to use this buffer (a const char* array) without using the filesystem (I could have saved this buffer in a file, then load the file, but no).

First, I create a memory DB :

    `mErrorCode = sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &mSqlDatabase, lMode, NULL);`

This returns SQLITE_OK, then I tried to use the buffer as a statement and call `preparev2(MyDB, MyBufferData, MyBufferLength, MyStatement, NULL)` but it's not really a statement, and it returns an error. Same result if I call directly `exec(MyDB, MyBufferData, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

I guess there is an appropriate method to achieve this as it might be common to load a DB from a stream or from decrypted data...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the proper way to do this is to create an [SQLite VFS layer](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html) around your buffer, as mentioned in [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg38736.html) thread. A possible/partial solution, [spmemvfs](http://code.google.com/p/sphivedb/downloads/list), is mentioned [here](http://www.pubbs.net/201005/sqlite/36639-sqlite-loading-sqlite3-db-into-memory.html), although I have never tried it.

If you don't need concurrency for your DB, creating your own VFS implementation should be quite simple.

Comment: Thank you ! I used spmemvfs and it works. However, if it can help someone out there, the file name specified in the _open() method should NOT be ":memory:" otherwise, it does not load the content of the buffer.

Comment: rockeye, can you post a working example? i can't seem to get it working using spmemvfs.